# How do I move a Matter.js body with arrow keys in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

I'm currently trying to make a 2d tank game in JavaScript for a school project and to deal with the physics I'm using the physics library matter.js, alongside p5.js for rendering.

So far I have a basic canvas with boundaries on the walls and floor so that objects can't go off-screen, however, the next task is to be able to move a box (that will later be a tank) left and right with the arrow keys. I've done something similar before in pure JS with simply using an Event Listener to tell when the left or right arrow key is being pressed down, and then redrawing the object 5 pixels to the left or right. However, this approach hasn't worked in Matter.js and it's left me absolutely stumped.

Here's the draw() function where I'm currently trying to experiment with different ways to figure this out:

```
function draw() {
    background(51);
    Engine.update(engine);
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].show();
    }
     if(rightPressed) {
         box1.position.x += 7
     }
    if(leftPressed) {
        Body.applyForce(box1, {x: box1.position.x, y: box1.position.y}, {x: 0.05, y: 0});
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
      boundaries[i].show();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        circles[i].show();
        if (circles[i].isOffScreen()) {
            circles[i].removeFromWorld();
            circles.splice(i, 1)
            i--;
        }
    }
}

setInterval(draw, 10)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty odd to use `setInterval(draw, 10)` if you're using p5.js. Why not use p5.js's provided `draw()` function which is automatically called in an optimized `requestAnimationFrame` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyIsDown() function to check specific key inputs.
An example being:

```
draw(){

   if(keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
      //code xyz
     }

}
```